# Replace values in a data frame

Tags: r, regex

I would like to replace some row values in a data frame which match a specific name format.

For example, in the dataframe below i need all the names of all 'Alkohol Free Beers' in the 'Type' column to be simply written as `Alkohol Free` and '5l beers' as `Beer 5l`

```
df <- data.frame(Type = c('Beer','Beer 1', 'Alkoholfree Beer', 'Beer Alkoholfree', 'Beer Alkfre', '0.33 Alko free beer', 'Beer 5l', '5l Beer', 'BeeR 5l'), total = sample(1:10, 9))

                 Type total
1                Beer     8
2              Beer 1     5
3    Alkoholfree Beer    10
4    Beer Alkoholfree     6
5         Beer Alkfre     4
6 0.33 Alko free beer     9
7             Beer 5l     7
8             5l Beer     2
9             BeeR 5l     3
```

Can i perform this using `replace()` or `which()` function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will generalize on your larger data set, but you can mutate the type variable using `case_when` from `dplyr` the following way:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
   mutate(Type = case_when(str_detect(Type, "Alk") ~ "Alkohol Free",
                          str_detect(Type, "5l") ~ "Beer 5l",
                          TRUE ~ "Beer"))
          Type total
1         Beer     5
2         Beer     6
3 Alkohol Free     4
4 Alkohol Free     9
5 Alkohol Free     7
6 Alkohol Free     3
7      Beer 5l     8
8      Beer 5l     1
9      Beer 5l    10
```

This solution uses `str_detect`from the `stringr` package to detect whether `Type` includes either "Alk" (denoting alcohol-free beers) or "5l" (denoting the 5 liter beers) and overwrites the column in the way you want. You didn't specify what you wanted to do with those beers that were neither alcohol-free nor 5 liter beers, so I made a third category simply called "Beer".

Comment: This approach could accomodate more complex patterns in your type variable, but on the provided data set, it works as is.

Comment: Yes this looks neat. Unable to test at the moment due to some tidyverse issues. I think this should work on my larger dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know on same.

```
df %>%
  mutate_all(funs(gsub("Alkoholfree","Alkohol free",.))) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(gsub("5l [bB]eers","Beer 5l",.)))
```

Output will be as follows.

```
> df %>%
+   mutate_all(funs(gsub("Alkoholfree","Alkohol free",.))) %>%
+   mutate_all(funs(gsub("5l [bB]eers","Beer 5l",.)))
                 Type total
1                Beer     8
2              Beer 1     2
3   Alkohol free Beer     9
4   Beer Alkohol free     4
5         Beer Alkfre     6
6 0.33 Alko free beer     5
7             Beer 5l     3
8             5l Beer     7
9             BeeR 5l    10
```